# Chaining side effects from spock stub with void return type

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I'm trying to test the following (contrived) code, which makes a call, and attempts one retry, if the call fails.

```
 public class MyObject
 {
    public void process(final Client client) throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            client.send();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            client.fix();
        }

        try
        {
            client.send();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        public void send() throws IOException {}

        public void fix() {}
    }
}
```

My testing strategy is to mock the `client` object and stub a response that will throw an exception on the first call to `send()` and then succeed on the second attempt.

Using spock, I have the following:

```
def "test method calls"() {
   setup:
   def MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
   def Client client = Mock(Client)

   when:
   myObject.process(client)

   then:
   2 * client.send() >>> {throw new IOException()} >> void
}
```

I've tried the above, and replacing void with null, and keep getting cast exceptions.

I've also tried:

```
2 * client.send() >>> [{throw new MyException()}, void]
```

How can I mock my desired response?

Comment: `client.send() >> { throw new MyException() } >> null`

Comment: I tried this, didn't work

Comment: Works fine for me, and I designed it to work this way. Perhaps you tried something slightly different, e.g. with  `>>>` instead of `>>` as in your question, which isn't going to work.

Comment: I confirm, Peter's solution works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test passes. I have added comments to show what each step indicates:

```
def "test method calls"() {
    given:
    def MyObject myObject = new MyObject()
    def MyObject.Client client = Mock(MyObject.Client)
    //The first time client.send() is called, throw an exception
    1 * client.send() >> {throw new IOException()}
    //The second time client.send() is called, do nothing. With the above, also defines that client.send() should be called a total of 2 times. 
    1 * client.send()
    when:
    myObject.process(client)
    then:
    noExceptionThrown() //Verifies that no exceptions are thrown
    1 * client.fix() // Verifies that client.fix() is called only once.
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I didn't realise that two separate stubs would chain together like that.

Comment: @DanielScott No problem. Found defining interactions with spock quite tricky to start with, but it's a great unit testing tool once you get your head round it.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine.

```
1*getName()>>"Hello"
1*getName()>>"Hello Java"
```

First Invocation im getting `"Hello"`.
Second Invocation im getting `"Hello Java`"